# SqlCe, EF5, IDENTITY_INSERT for table with autogenerated Ids

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

So I need to move data from existing database SqLite, to new SqlCe database. I load entities with NHibernate, as this is the DAL I use for the SqLite database. New database (SqlCe) is created with EF Code-First / DbContext.

Now I simply want to make a one-time-use method for each table to "manually" insert entities with their existing Ids (as I want to preserve the Ids). The tables use autogenerated Ids, so I need to override this. Question is, what is the easiest way to do that? Can it be done with the DbContext?

Preferably it should be strongly typed, but so far I tried using the SqlCeConnection .CreateCommand / .ExecuteNonQuery, with hard-typed SQL. But not sure of the syntax here, as I don't know much SQL.

For the code below, various attempts of specifying variable-keys produce the following exceptions;

> @0 => Message=A parameter is missing. [ Parameter ordinal = 8 ]
>
> '{0}' => Message=Data conversion failed. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 2 ]
>
> {0} => Message=Data conversion failed. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 2 ]

```
        var conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + DbFileName);
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = @"SET IDENTITY_INSERT AccountBases ON;";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(
               @"INSERT INTO AccountBases (
                AccStartTime, AccType, Broker, 
                ClientID, ConnType, CreationDate, 
                Guid, Id, Name, 
                Strategy)  
               VALUES({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9} );",
               a.AccStartTime, 
               a.AccType, 
               a.Broker, 
               a.ClientID, 
               a.ConnType, 
               a.CreationDate, 
               a.Guid, 
               a.Id, 
               a.Name, 
               a.Strategy);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Never format strings for your queries. Always use parametrized queries.

In your particular case, the most probable issue is that you pass a datetime (CreationDate) without quoting it like this: '{0}'.